# Qt Designer and PyQt5 custom plugin loading TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm having a problem loading custom PyQt5 plugins with Qt Designer. The example plugins available on [GitHub](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/designer/plugins) were working and I used them to create my own plugin which was working as well. Then yesterday Designer stopped loading any of them. When I start Designer from the CLI I get:

```
TypeError: unwrapinstance() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PyAnalogClockPlugin
TypeError: unwrapinstance() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not BubblesPlugin
TypeError: unwrapinstance() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not CounterLabelPlugin
TypeError: unwrapinstance() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PyDateEditPlugin
TypeError: unwrapinstance() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PyDateTimeEditPlugin
TypeError: unwrapinstance() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not HelloGLWidgetPlugin
TypeError: unwrapinstance() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not MultiPageWidgetPlugin
TypeError: unwrapinstance() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PolygonWidgetPlugin
TypeError: unwrapinstance() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PyDemoPlugin
TypeError: unwrapinstance() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PythonConsolePlugin
```

I don't know where to start and Google-ing the issue didn't help either. I'm using Python 3.6.6, Qt 5.11.1, PyQt5 5.11.2, and Linux 4.17.5-1-ARCH.

What is causing this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: I've updated the OP with system information for clarity.

Comment: Fixed: https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2018-July/040545.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed with a PyQt5 update: [riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2018-July/040545.html](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2018-July/040545.html)